# Data attribute changed in the DOM but ignored by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I did a quick fiddle to show the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nm3Ma/1/

Take this html:

```
<div class="myclass" data-number="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-number="2"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-number="3"></div>
```

and this js

```
$(".myclass").each(function(){      
    var number = $(this).data('number');
    if( number>1 )
    {
        $(this).attr('data-number', number-1 );
    }
    $('body').append($(this).data('number')+'<br/>'); 
});
```

The code actually changes the HTML to:

```
<div class="myclass" data-number="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-number="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-number="2"></div>
```

But it still prints:

```
1
2
3
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses an internal data structure to store the data values, the `data-*` attributes are used to initiate the data values if the key is not found in the internal structure. So when you read the value for the second time it is reading the value from the internal structure instead of the attribute, so changes made to the attribute will not be visible to it.

You need to use the setter version of [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value) to set the data value

```
$(".myclass").each(function(){      
    var number = $(this).data('number');
    if( number>1 )
    {
        $(this).data('number', number-1 );
    }
    $('body').append($(this).data('number')+'<br/>'); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/27U3q/)

Or use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to both read and write value

```
$(".myclass").each(function () {
    var number = $(this).attr('data-number');
    if (number > 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-number', number - 1);
    }
    $('body').append($(this).attr('data-number') + '<br/>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EH529/)

Comment: I see thank you very much, I think I'll go with the attr approach for consistency.